# Red5 Error creating bean with name 'web.scope' in fresh installation on windows in demo apps

Tags: java, red5

I am new to Red5. i just downloaded Red5 windows installer 1.0.5 and installed in c:\red5 direcroty on my windows 7 x64bit with java version 1.7.0_45.

i am getting following errors and no demo in webapps is working.

```
2015-02-10 19:51:22,696 [Launcher:/] INFO  org.red5.server.scope.Scope - Invalid scope name, null is not allowed
2015-02-10 19:51:22,698 [Launcher:/] WARN  org.red5.server.scope.Scope - Invalid scope rejected: Scope [name=null, path=/default, type=APPLICATION, autoStart=true, creationTime=1423579882660, depth=1, enabled=true, running=false]
2015-02-10 19:51:22,698 [Launcher:/] WARN  org.red5.server.scope.Scope - Scope not added to parent
2015-02-10 19:51:22,699 [Launcher:/] INFO  org.red5.server.scope.WebScope - Webscope already registered
2015-02-10 19:51:22,709 [Launcher:/chat] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'web.scope' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.red5.server.scope.Scope$ConcurrentScopeSet.keySet()    Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:479) [tomcatplugin-1.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.red5.server.scope.Scope$ConcurrentScopeSet.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
at org.red5.server.scope.Scope$ConcurrentScopeSet.hasName(Scope.java:1411) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.red5.server.scope.Scope.hasChildScope(Scope.java:819) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.red5.server.scope.Scope.init(Scope.java:872) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.red5.server.scope.WebScope.register(WebScope.java:225) ~[red5.jar:na]
at org.red5.server.scope.WebScope.afterPropertiesSet(WebScope.java:111) ~[red5.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the classes being compiled with JDK8 and being run on JDK7 or older. I updated the release to fix this issue, download the newer archives and try again or update your JDK to version 8.

Comment: I'm using `Java1.7.0_79` I'm having the same error using the latest download from the Github repo. I can't update the system to Java 8 just yet, so I was wondering if there's any other solutions I could try to get it working.

Comment: @TomHart which latest download? Did you try the nightly builds on Apache? https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/OpenMeetings/

Comment: Ahh no, I just got the latest release from Github. Turns out I needed to stick with an older version anyway to get it to work with HDFVR.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same issue in Linux. I think it's a bug as 1.0.4 doesn't do this.